# Why only one free() works for this segment of code?

Tags: c

I use free() to free the structure I allocated before, and I want to test if they have successfully free, but I get only one of them free why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student{
    char *name;
    struct student *next;
}student;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    student *a=malloc(sizeof(student));
    a->name="echo";
    student *b=malloc(sizeof(student));
    b->name="harry";
    a->next=b;
    b->next=NULL;
    free(a);
    free(b);
    printf("%s\n", a->name);
    printf("%s\n", b->name);
    return 0;
}
```

and I got this output.Why?

```
(null)
harry
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you access memory after you told the system to take it back?

Comment: I expect that print b->name should return a null, because in my opinion b is freed, and the address which used to belong to b should no longer exist, so the system can't access the freed address.

Comment: The address does still "exist", or you would get a segfault. Whether the address has already been used for another purpose - in one case yes, in the other no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "test" if they have successfully been freed, trying to access any memory that has been freed is undefined behavior, instead of testing just accept and move on.

Answer (score 2):

You have `free`d the memory but that doesn't mean the pointer has been invalidated by the system. In your second case, the data where it pointed to has not yet been re-used so `printf` finds it and can print.

- In the first case the memory has been re-used or reset. `print` finds a null pointer.
- In the second case the memory has not yet been re-used: `printf` finds it and can print it.

But this undefined behavior and anything could have happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can better use free along with setting the variable to `NULL`.

```
free(b);
b = NULL;
free(a);
a = NULL;
```

When you call `free`, the variable is marked for recollection. And when that recollection of the memory allocated should happen is up to the underlying OS. You should not access the freed block.